# How to position the icon and text horizontally using SweetAlert2 library

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to change the position of an icon in SweetAlert2 to line up horizontally with a piece of text. (I think I should use `display: flex`, but as far as I know there is no way to put the icon class inside a `div` next to the text class).

This is how the alert looks at the moment:

[image: How I have the alert now]

And this is how I want it to look:

[image: How I want it to be]

Here is the code of my alert:

```
Swal.fire({
    html: '<span class="text">Congratulations</span>',
    icon: 'success',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    position: 'bottom-end',
    customClass: {
    popup: 'swal-wide',
    icon: 'icon-class'
   }
})
```

And here is my CSS file (it currently has nothing important at all):

```
.icon-class{
    font-size: 10px;
}

.text{
    font-size: 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 761px){
    .swal-wide{
        width: 23% !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px){
    .swal-wide{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see anything in the [SweetAlert2 documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) that would let you do this, but I could be mistaken.

However, you are correct, it is possible to use `divs` and `flexbox` to achieve the effect you want, however, it is a little bit fiddly.

If you disable the buttons then you will need to implement some other method to remove the sweet alert box.

The icon is drawn as an `svg` inside the `html` property, all within some `divs`.

```js
Swal.fire({
  html: '<div class="container"><div><svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="5 5 40 40"><path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/></svg></div><div class="textDiv">Congratulations</div></div>',
  position: 'bottom-end',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  customClass: {
    popup: 'swal-wide',
    icon: 'icon-class'
  }
})
```

```css
.icon-class {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 761px) {
  .swal-wide {
    width: 40% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .swal-wide {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

.checkmark {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 2px green;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  ;
}

.textDiv {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```